# Split a large pandas column and affiancate as new column without considering index

Tags: pandas

As stated in title, I need to split a pandas dataframe with  columns containing million of rows in 2 equal parts. Than I need to merge the second half as new columns.

Here a small sample:

```
AAA 125

BBB 467

XXX 321

YYY 568
```

Must be reshaped in:

```
AAA 125 XXX 321

BBB 467 YYY 568
```

I try with append and concat, but row don't merge and show NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is by horizontally stacking the underlying array

```
pd.DataFrame(np.hstack( (df.values[:len(df)//2], df.values[len(df)//2:])))

    0   1   2   3
0   AAA 125 XXX 321
1   BBB 467 YYY 568
```

Option 2: Using reshape

```
pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.values, (df.shape[0]//2, df.shape[1] * 2)))
```

Comment: Hpstack() do exactly what I'm searching for. Thanks.